# How to Install node8 and latest npm in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-16.04

Hi i have installed node v4.2.6 and npm 3.5.2 in my ubuntu but now when i try to install latest version or node6.x then i am getting some errors in my terminal of Packages 404  Not Found. i have also attached the screenshot. please let me know how can i fix it?

i also have tried :-

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
# Then install with:
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

still got the same output and i guess i made one mistake by running a command :-

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/:\/\/(archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com)/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

as mentioned in https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/

[Here is the output of sudo apt-get update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NdZm.png)

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what is your ubuntu version but if it's on 16.4 you can do this commands :

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
```

after that :

```
$ curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
```

and after do this commands :

```
$ nano install_nvm.sh
```

and after that close the nano and do this command :

```
$ bash install_nvm.sh
```

It will install the software into a subdirectory of your home directory at `~/.nvm`. It will also add the necessary lines to your `~/.profile` file to use the file.

To gain access to the nvm functionality, you'll need to log out and log back in again, or you can source the `~/.profile` file so that your current session knows about the changes:

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

Now that you have nvm installed, you can install isolated Node.js versions.

To find out the versions of Node.js that are available for installation, you can type:

```
$ nvm ls-remote
```

and the out put looks like this :

```
....
v5.8.0
v5.9.0
v5.9.1
v5.10.0
v5.10.1
v5.11.0
v6.0.0
...
v8.4.0
```

now you can simply type this command to install the v8.4.0 of nodejs :

```
$ nvm install 8.4.0
```

and at the last step you can type this command to use the last version :

```
$ nvm use 8.4.0
```

and it's done!

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong package url, you must use

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Reference: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) as a nodejs and npm manager.
Then you can easily install required version of node with nvm install node x.x 
command